# How can I see my own profile while inside a game?

Tags: diablo-iii

While I'm inside a game, I can see my achievements (pressing <kbd>Y</kbd> or from <kbd>esc</kbd> menu) and I can see my friend's achievements, and also their profiles. But I can't see my own profile?

From the main menu I can see my own profile (play time for each character, equipment, skills etc) but not while I'm inside a game?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Updated for patch 2.0.1**:

Press shift-'P' to see your own profile.

('P' will open the new paragon screen)

Comment: Thanks! That feels pretty obvious now... although I think it's strange that there's is no option in the UI to see it ingame, since there is a dedicated button for achievements, and I was looking for something similar. Oh, well

Comment: P now opens the paragon menu so it no longer opens the uer's profile.

Comment: @z- Thanks for alerting me! I've checked in-game, and shift-P opens the profile screen now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write something, rightclick your name (or others), and view profile, achivements, invite etc.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know there was a contextual menu on chat names